# constexpr to construct objects with private members

Tags: c++, c++14

I have the following code that compiles and behaves as expected:

```
struct A
{
    //private:
        int v;

    friend constexpr A f(int v);
};

constexpr A f(int v)
{
    return A{v};
}

constexpr A operator""_A(unsigned long long v)
{
    return f(static_cast<int>(v));
}
```

I can construct objects of type `A` like this:

```
auto a = 1_A;
```

If I make the value `A::v` private I get compilation error

> No matching constructor for initialization of 'A'

If I add the constructor to `A`, I get a different copilation error:

> Constexpr function's return type 'A' is not a literal type

Is there a way to make `A::v` private and still have `constexpr` functions to construct objects of type `A`?

Comment: Can you show the ctor you've added? Was it `constexpr`?

Comment: @Angew No, it wasn't... Thanks:) That was the problem - calling non constexpr function from constexpr one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class is a literal type if:

- it has a trivial destructor
- it's an aggregate, or it has at least one non-copy, non-move **constexpr** constructor
- all of its base classes and non-static members are non-volatile literal types

Therefore, when adding a constructor to a class which you want to be a literal type, you must mark that constructor as `constexpr`.